# How do I retreive the background color from a control?

Tags: winapi, colors, background-color

How can I retrieve the background color from a given control?

I'm looking for as general a solution as possible, including the default colors of a control. Is it possible to do this?

The closest I have gotten so far is the find of `GetPixel()`, but I realize it's far from a perfect solution. If I have text or something over the control -- that basically all controls have, it leads to the wrong result.

Comment: You can't. Any control can handle `WM_ERASEBKGND` and do whatever.

Comment: Doesn't the windows hold that colors somewhere internally?

Comment: No, it doesn't. There is no "BackgroundColor" property for Win32 windows. There is a system brush associated with an HWND, but that's rarely used when actually painting the control. I think it's just for `WM_ERASEBKGND`. What exactly would the background color be for a control that is painted with a gradient? The color of a control is determined by the library maintaining that control. There are "system colors", though. If you want the default system color for a button, you could call `GetSysColor(COLOR_BTNFACE)`. If that button has it's WM_PAINT overridden, it could be anything.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What actual problem are trying to solve?

Comment: Sure, you can call [GetClassInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclassinfow) and get back a [WNDCLASS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-wndclassw) that has an `hbrBackground` field. [GetObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getobject) can yield a [LOGBRUSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-logbrush) with an `lbColor` field. Though that's only meaningful for some brush types, and if the control actually uses it. Neither one is madated.

Comment: @Andy I realized that due to brushing system, this doesn't really make any sense to copy a background color

Comment: @Jabberwocky Make the control have same color as its parent, to get a transparent background effect

Comment: What type of control do you want to set, if it is a control like static control, you can use the brush metioned above in the `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` message.